# Loop over all current view ports

Tags: python, scripting, maya

I can switch off NURBS view in a specific window with

```
modelEditor -e -nurbsCurves $b modelPanel3;
```

where modelPanel3 is the viewport of choice.

How do I do that for *all* viewports currently visible? Is there a what to get an to return such information as an array or do you have to loop through a number and see if the view port visibility is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question then:

To loop through the viewports

```
# import python maya commands 
 import maya.cmds as cmds

# Create a list of ALL viewports
viewports = cmds.getPanel( all = True)

# Get the current viewport
vp = cmds.getPanel( withFocus = True) # current viewport
current = cmds.modelEditor( vp, q = True, nurbsCurves = True)

for view in viewports:
  if 'modelPanel' in view:
  # check to see if the item in lists is a viewport
  # is one of the model panels.
  # The list is quite big and we only need up to four

    print view # prints the current viewport

    #Swap the NURBS visibility around
    cmds.modelEditor( view, edit = True, nurbsCurves = not(current))
```

I hope that helped me as much as it did you. Yes it did. Thanks